# SwiftUI: Add shadow to Button's text

Tags: button, text, swiftui, shadow

I've got a button style, and I need to add shadow to the text using this style. What I am trying to do is:

```
struct A: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration
            .label
            .shadow()
    }
}
```

But the shadow is not there for some reason, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Thank you guys, what I did wrong was I used a radius of 20 so I was sure to see it, but it made the shadow so transparent I didn't see it at all) P.S. I omitted shadow() parameters to not obstruct the simpleness of the case, but I see it was my downfall, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the least, you're missing a `radius` parameter. But, even then, it'll be subtle.  If you give it some more information, you can make it more obvious and then adjust it to fit your needs:

```
.shadow(color: .pink, radius: 4, x: 5, y: 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed shadow colour and radius

```
struct FilledButton: ButtonStyle {
   func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
       configuration
         .label
         .shadow(color: .green, radius: 1
                , x: 1.5, y: 1.5)
   }
}
```

Then, Use it in your body

```
var body: some View {
    Button("Button 1") {}
        .buttonStyle(FilledButton())
}
```

Here is output

[image]